# Provide some context in push notifications for the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I frequently get push notifications that look something like this:

[image: screenshot]

It's as if Stack Exchange wants to tell me about their dog!

Currently, I have no way of knowing whether this is a comment, answer, or chat message without actually tapping on the notification and opening the app.

Furthermore, it does not indicate what site this was on. Perhaps it was on Pets.SE, or it could have been an off-topic comment on Stack Overflow. With the current format, there's no way of knowing.

Push notifications should provide more of this contextual information.

Comment: I recognize it's tricky to save space, but I'd like to see either the author or the question title - I can't often guess which conversation is being continued.

Comment: With iOS 10 it would be even cooler if they implemented a notification extension to provide custom UI when the notification was viewed (without even opening the app)